# PHP Slim v3 post method 405 (used POSTMAN testing!)

Tags: php, slim

I can't post data, the testing are using POSTMAN, the test code :

```php
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../config/config.php';

$app = new Slim\App(['settings' => $config]);

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $db = $c['settings']['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db['host'] . ';dbname=' . $db['dbname'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};

$app->post('api/menu-list', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $db = $this->db;
    $insertData = [
        'router' => $args['rouster'],
        'show_name' => $args['show_name'],
        'is_lv_one_menu' => $args['is_lv_one_menu']
    ];
    $query = "INSERT INTO menu_list (router, show_name, is_lv_one_menu) VALUES (:router, :show_name, :is_lv_one_menu)";
    try {
        $db->prepare($query)->execute($insertData);
        $response->getBody()->write('Data success, the insert id is : ' . $db->lastInsertId());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response->getBody()->write('Data insert error, take look : ');
        $response->getBody()->write($e);
    }
});
```

The POSTMAN screenshots are here:

[image]

[image]

Maybe problem are not apache, is any help? thank you.

Edit:

I don't know what happens, I fix args, the problem is gone, and insert success.

```php
function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
    $db = $this->db;
    $insertData = ['router' => 'testRouter2', 'show_name' => 'test2', 'is_lv_one_menu' => 'N'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO menu_list (router, show_name, is_lv_one_menu) VALUES (:router, :show_name, :is_lv_one_menu)";
    try {
        $db->prepare($query)->execute($insertData);
        $response->getBody()->write('Data success, the insert id is : ' . $db->lastInsertId());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response->getBody()->write('Data insert error, take look : ');
        $response->getBody()->write($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not returning  `$response` in your route callback

Comment: really? but official doc does not make this requirement, https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#post-route

Comment: The statement of zedling is correct. You habe to return a response. `return $response;`

Comment: I know, I must return response because PSR-7, but I fix some code, still not return, and success, everything are weird

Comment: you post an array of object from postman, but you access it like it is just an object;
either remove the `[]` from around the data you send, or handle it as an array of objects in the callback

Comment: Is there  typo in `$args['rouster']`?